# What's the meaning of this kind of loop: for(int i=0;i &lt; 1000; i++)

Tags: java, for-loop

What's the meaning of this kind of loop:

```
for(int i=0;i &lt; 1000; i++)
```

Comment: Do you know about HTML entities?

Comment: It means the web sometimes screws up encoding/decoding the `<` character.  I believe that is supposed to be `for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the for loop exactly work out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345748/how-does-the-for-loop-exactly-work-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&lt;` is an `html` entity that represents the less than (`<`) sign. Your `for(int i=0;i &lt; 1000; i++)` is just `for(int i=0;i < 1000; i++)` in `html`.