# Javascript document.write issue with loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to let the code create a data file for my marzipano project, it uses this data.js and I don't want to create every link for each project so I tried to loop it but it doesnt print it into my html page. I want to print it as a text so I can copy and paste the result in my js file, is there a way to fix my code or a better way to do it?

P.S: I'm a total noob with javascript

Thank you in advance

```js
function auto(number){
 i = 0;
 while (i < number) {
  //Fist Scene
  if(i === 0){
   document.write('
   <p>    
    {
      "id": "0",
      "name": "0",
      "levels": [
     {
       "tileSize": 256,
       "size": 256,
       "fallbackOnly": true
     },
     {
       "tileSize": 512,
       "size": 512
     },
     {
       "tileSize": 512,
       "size": 1024
     },
     {
       "tileSize": 512,
       "size": 2048
     }
      ],
      "faceSize": 2000,
      "initialViewParameters": {
     "yaw": -3.0907815953112916,
     "pitch": 0.06648956035942888,
     "fov": 1.5707963267948966
      },
      "linkHotspots": [
     {
       "yaw": -3.128953846954726,
       "pitch": 0.47317799909128944,
       "rotation": 0,
       "target": "1"    
     }
      ],
      "infoHotspots": []
    },</p>
    ')
  }
  
  //Last Scene
  else if (i === number){
   document.write('
   <p>
   {
     "id": "'i'",
     "name": "'i'",
     "levels": [
    {
      "tileSize": 256,
      "size": 256,
      "fallbackOnly": true
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 512
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 1024
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 2048
    }
     ],
     "faceSize": 2000,
     "initialViewParameters": {
    "yaw": -3.1332154632455715,
    "pitch": 0.062442602034723294,
    "fov": 1.5707963267948966
     },
     "linkHotspots": [
    {
      "yaw": 0.008275683165861025,
      "pitch": 0.3876084470351344,
      "rotation": 0,
      "target": "'i-1'"
    }
     ],
     "infoHotspots": []
   }</p>'
   )
  }
  
  //Actual loop
  else if (i < number){
   document.write('
   {
     "id": "i",
     "name": "i",
     "levels": [
    {
      "tileSize": 256,
      "size": 256,
      "fallbackOnly": true
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 512
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 1024
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 2048
    }
     ],
     "faceSize": 2000,
     "initialViewParameters": {
    "yaw": -3.0859786632885857,
    "pitch": 0.058860826755053,
    "fov": 1.5707963267948966
     },
     "linkHotspots": [
    {
      "yaw": 0.007751782217697567,
      "pitch": 0.39202518148107757,
      "rotation": 0,
      "target": "'i-1'"
    },
    {
      "yaw": -3.1285088198075375,
      "pitch": 0.48530966110218543,
      "rotation": 0,
      "target": "'i+1'"
    }
     ],
     "infoHotspots": []
   },<br>
   ')
  }
 
  }
   
  
 }
}

auto(13);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="auto.js"></script> 
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One error I see immediately is that JavaScript doesn't allow for multiple line strings unless you use backticks

Comment: Also, make sure you increment `i` inside you `while` or you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: So I tried this: https://gist.github.com/thriskel/3209b4d969131451ee5e5184775a0ad9  but it gave an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" after " document.write(` "

Answer (score 0):

First of all have to say something:

1. Don't use `document.write()` in loops. It'll rewrite your document itself.
2. Use backticks(`) to wrap string when it is multi-line string.
3. It's better to use `pre` tag to show formatted data like `JSON` or any `code` snippets.
4. While using `while` loop take care of `incrementer` and `decrementer` in your `while` block to prevent `infinite` looping.

I think the below solution works for you.

```js
function auto(number){
    var e = document.getElementById("data");
 i = 0;
    var html = "";
 while (i <= number) {
  //Fist Scene
  if(i === 0){
   html += `
   <pre>    
    {
      "id": "` + i + `",
      "name": "0",
      "levels": [
     {
       "tileSize": 256,
       "size": 256,
       "fallbackOnly": true
     },
     {
       "tileSize": 512,
       "size": 512
     },
     {
       "tileSize": 512,
       "size": 1024
     },
     {
       "tileSize": 512,
       "size": 2048
     }
      ],
      "faceSize": 2000,
      "initialViewParameters": {
     "yaw": -3.0907815953112916,
     "pitch": 0.06648956035942888,
     "fov": 1.5707963267948966
      },
      "linkHotspots": [
     {
       "yaw": -3.128953846954726,
       "pitch": 0.47317799909128944,
       "rotation": 0,
       "target": "1"    
     }
      ],
      "infoHotspots": []
    },</pre>
    `;
  }
  
  //Last Scene
  else if (i === number){
   html += `
   <pre>
   {
     "id": "` + i + `",
     "name": "` + i + `",
     "levels": [
    {
      "tileSize": 256,
      "size": 256,
      "fallbackOnly": true
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 512
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 1024
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 2048
    }
     ],
     "faceSize": 2000,
     "initialViewParameters": {
    "yaw": -3.1332154632455715,
    "pitch": 0.062442602034723294,
    "fov": 1.5707963267948966
     },
     "linkHotspots": [
    {
      "yaw": 0.008275683165861025,
      "pitch": 0.3876084470351344,
      "rotation": 0,
      "target": "` + (i-1) + `"
    }
     ],
     "infoHotspots": []
   }</pre>
   `;
  }
  
  //Actual loop
  else if (i < number){
   html += `
   <pre>{
     "id": "` + i + `",
     "name": "` + i + `",
     "levels": [
    {
      "tileSize": 256,
      "size": 256,
      "fallbackOnly": true
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 512
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 1024
    },
    {
      "tileSize": 512,
      "size": 2048
    }
     ],
     "faceSize": 2000,
     "initialViewParameters": {
    "yaw": -3.0859786632885857,
    "pitch": 0.058860826755053,
    "fov": 1.5707963267948966
     },
     "linkHotspots": [
    {
      "yaw": 0.007751782217697567,
      "pitch": 0.39202518148107757,
      "rotation": 0,
      "target": "` + (i-1) + `"
    },
    {
      "yaw": -3.1285088198075375,
      "pitch": 0.48530966110218543,
      "rotation":0,
      "target": "` + (i+1) + `"
    }
     ],
     "infoHotspots": []
   }</pre>
   `;
  }
 i++;
  }
  e.innerHTML = html;
}

auto(13);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="auto.js"></script> 
  <div id="data"><div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much but how do I get the code to increase the number in "id", "name" and "target?

Comment: Where do you want to give `id`s?

Comment: where I commented the code above, as //heeere, I also tried to use the code but it didn't loop. the browser debugger gave this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Comment: Thanks but why does the explorer debugger says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" pointing to the line 147 : "e.innerHTML = html;"?

Comment: keep your script below the `<body>` tag

Comment: I'm sorry for disturbing you so much but the loop stops before getting to the number I enter like I execute the function like "auto(14);" and it stops at 13 so it doesnt use the fist else if

Comment: Not an issue, I'm here to help. Let me correct it. You want `ids` from 0-13 or 1-14 ?

Comment: I want the code: else if(i === number){execute} so if it is the last number it executes example: auto(5); <--- it should execute first if ( i === 0) for zero value then else if ( i < number ) {execute} for 1,2,3 and 4. then at last else if (i === number) for 5 value

Comment: Now check the updated one. Just keep `while(i <= number)`

Comment: "First of all have to say something" — You've marked up the list that follows that as a quote. Who are you quoting? If nobody, then please remove the quote markup.

Comment: @Quentin, Okay Thank you.

Comment: Tried that but that just repeats the else if( i <= number) for 4 and 5, if I use  (i == number) doesnt call the else if. (P.S: what is Quentin taking about?)

Comment: so if using i <= number it reaches the last number why it doesnt work with i == number?

Comment: It's a simple looping concept with applied condition. Manually check the loop. You will get it.

Comment: I managed to make it work by using else if( i == (number - 1)){do} but I still don't get why is it stopping before getting to the last number, is the else if (i < number) messing with the else if (i == number)?

Comment: see this for how loop works http://stackoverflow.com/a/25345805/4355342