# for loop actual value is different from what I expect

Tags: java

```java
int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    
    if(i == 2) {
        i += 4;
        // continue;
    }
    
}

System.out.println(i);
```

In the code above, I expected that int i = 6 would ultimately come out, but 7 came out.
Why is that so?

Comment: Hi and welcome!
Take a look this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345748/how-does-the-for-loop-exactly-work-out 
Make sure you understand how for loop works!
Have a good day!

Comment: Check the difference between "continue" and "break" and you will get the answer. Also read the JVM language specification for loop section.

Comment: Before posting here, always study [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) provided free of cost by Oracle Corp.

Comment: i++ is executed before i<3 is checked. So, when i == 2 and i+=4 happens, one additional i++ is executed which makes i==7.
If you would 'break', the loop would be left immediately.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your loop is equivalent to

```
int i = 0;  
while (i < 3) {
    if(i == 2) {
        i += 4;
    }
    i++;  
}
```

`i` is incremented after entering the loop

Comment: thank you so much.

i finally understand!!!!